# Probability predictions with cumulative link mixed models

Tags: r, regression, ordinal, mixed-models

I am trying to fit cumulative link mixed models with the `ordinal` package but there is something I do not understand about obtaining the prediction probabilities. I use the following example from the `ordinal` package:

```
   library(ordinal)
data(soup)
## More manageable data set:
dat <- subset(soup, as.numeric(as.character(RESP)) <=  24)
dat$RESP <- dat$RESP[drop=TRUE]
m1 <- clmm2(SURENESS ~ PROD, random = RESP, data = dat, link="logistic",  Hess = TRUE,doFit=T)
summary(m1)
str(dat)
```

Now I am trying to get predictions of probabilities for a new dataset

```
newdata1=data.frame(PROD=factor(c("Ref", "Ref")), SURENESS=factor(c("6","6")))
```

with

```
predict(m1, newdata=newdata1)
```

but I am getting the following error

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there something in the syntax of `predict.clmm2()` wrong? Generally which probabilities does does predict.clmm2() output? The `Pr(J<j)` or `Pr(J=j)`? Could someone point me to information (site, books) material regarding fitting categorical (ordinal) ordinal mixed models specifically with R. From my search in the literature and net, most researchers fit these kind of models with SAS.

Comment: You *probably* need to do something like `newdata1=data.frame(PROD=factor(c("Ref","Ref") , levels = c("Ref","Somethingelse"), ... )` - the error states you can't predict something with less than 2 factor levels (which you have).

Comment: (Disclaimer: I don't know anything about CLMMs) In your model formula, `SURENESS` appears to be your response variable, but you use it in your newdata instead of SOUPTYPE. Also, you leave PROD out of your original formula but include it in your newdata. Was that intentional? In any event, When I run the code, regardless whether I use SOUPTYPE or SURENESS in newdata, R tells me the other variable is missing (i.e. I'm getting a different error from you, R 2.15.0)

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it but still spits the same error.

Comment: @DavidMarx: `predict.clmm2` requires that the response variable be in the newdata argument, as well as requiring that the factor levels match the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say what you corrected, but when I use this, I get no error:

```
newdata1=data.frame(PROD=factor(c("Test", "Test"), levels=levels(dat$PROD)), 
                    SURENESS=factor(c("1","1")) )
predict(m1, newdata=newdata1)
```

The output from predict.clmm2 with a newdata argument will not make much sense unless you get all the factor levels aligned so they are in the agreement with the input data:

```
> newdata1=data.frame(
                PROD=factor(c("Ref", "Test"), levels=levels(dat$PROD)), 
                SURENESS=factor(c("1","1")) )
> predict(m1, newdata=newdata1)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Not very interesting. The prediction is for an outcome with only one level to have a probability of 1 of being in that level. (A vacuous prediction.) But recreating the structure of the original ordered outcomes is more meaningful:

```
> newdata1=data.frame(
             PROD=factor(c("Ref", "Test"), levels=levels(dat$PROD)), 
             SURENESS=factor(c("1","1"), levels=levels(dat$SURENESS)) , )
> predict(m1, newdata=newdata1)
[1] 0.20336975 0.03875713
```

You can answer the question in the comments by assembling all the predictions for various levels:

```
> sapply(as.character(1:6), function(x){ newdata1=data.frame(PROD=factor(c("Ref", "Test"), levels=levels(dat$PROD)), SURENESS=factor(c(x,x), levels=levels(dat$SURENESS))  );predict(m1, newdata=newdata1)})
              1          2          3          4         5         6
[1,] 0.20336975 0.24282083 0.10997039 0.07010327 0.1553313 0.2184045
[2,] 0.03875713 0.07412618 0.05232823 0.04405965 0.1518367 0.6388921
> out <- .Last.value
> rowSums(out)
[1] 1 1
```

The probabilities are `Pr(J=j|X=x & Random=all)`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I missed the fact that its important to spacify matcing values **and** labels for the categorical regressors. Is this specific to `predict.clmm2()` ? Do you also happen to know what kind of probabilities are in the output of `predict.clmm2()`? Are they Pr(J<j) or Pr(J=j)?

Comment: Not just the regressors, but also the outcomes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to check, the fits are of the model `log(odds)=a+bx` right? I am asking because other programs tend to fit `log(odds)=a-bx`

Comment: You should study the vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_intro.pdf . It looks like the clm package uses follows the convention you attribute to "other programs". I think it lets the probabilities sum to unity.

Comment: @42- Thanks for you instructive example. I was wondering whether it is possible to include the posterior means of the random effects into the predictions. When including the second level `RESP` into the data frame: `newdata1=data.frame(
    PROD=factor(c("Ref", "Test"), levels=levels(dat$PROD)), 
    RESP=factor(c("1", "3"), levels=levels(dat$RESP)),
    SURENESS=factor(c("1","1"), levels=levels(dat$SURENESS)))` and feeding it into the prediction sequence for various RESP level, probabilities remain the same which implies the prediction only evaluates the fixed part?

Comment: I wrote a long response that just barely fit in the comment space, but then realized I probably did not really understand the question. I suspect it is more appropriate for CrossValidated.com anyway. (I don't consider myself an expert in mixed models. I was not surprised that ME-predictions would only be affected by variations in FE variables, but I was not at all confident that my speculations about your options would be valid.)