# Loop through a character vector to use in a function

Tags: r, loops

I am conducting a methodcomparison study, comparing measurements from two different systems. My dataset has a large number of columns with variabels containing measurements from one of the two systems.

aX and bX are both measures of X, but from system a and b. I have about 80 pairs of variabels like this.

A simplified version of my data looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  ID = as.factor(rep(1:2, each=10)),
  aX = rep(1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2),
  bX = rep(1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2),
  aY = rep(1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5), 2),
  bY = rep(1:10-rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2))

head(df)

  ID       aX       bX       aY         bY
1  1 1.686773 2.755891 2.459489 -0.6793398
2  1 3.091822 3.194922 3.391068  1.0513939
3  1 3.582186 3.689380 4.037282  1.8061642
4  1 5.797640 3.892650 4.005324  3.0269025
5  1 6.164754 6.562465 6.309913  4.6885298
6  1 6.589766 6.977533 6.971936  5.2074973
```

I am trying to loop through the elements of a character vector, and use the elements to point to columns in the dataframe. But I keep getting error messages when I try to call functions with variable names generated in the loop.

For simplicity, I have changed the loop to include a linear model as this produces the same type of error as I have in my original script.

```
#This line is only included to show that
#the formula used in the loop works when
#called with directly with the "real" column names

(broom::glance(lm(aX~bX, data = df)))$r.squared

[1] 0.9405218

#Now I try the loop

varlist <- c("X", "Y")

for(i in 1:length(varlist)){
  aVAR <- paste0("a", varlist[i])
  bVAR <- paste0("b", varlist[i]) 

  #VAR and cVAR appear to have names identical column names in the df dataframe
  print(c(aVAR, bVAR))

  #Try the formula with the loop variable names
  print((broom::glance(lm(aVAR~bVAR, data = df)))$r.squared)
  }
```

The error messages I get when calling the functions from inside the loop vary according to the function I am calling, the common denominator for all the errors is that the occur when I try to use the character vector (varlist) to pick out specific columns.

Example of error messages:

```
rmcorr(ID, aVAR, bVAR, df)

Error in rmcorr(ID, aVAR, bVAR, df) : 
  'Measure 1' and 'Measure 2' must be numeric
```

or

```
broom::glance(lm(aVAR~bVAR, data = df))

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can you help me understand what goes wrong in the loop? Or suggest and show another way to acomplish what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables aren't evaluated in formulas (the things with `~`).

You can type

```
bert ~ ernie
```

and not get an error even if variables named `bert` and `ernie` do not exist. Formula store relationships between symbols/names and does not attempt to evaulate them. Also note we are not using quotes here. Variable names (or symbols) are not interchangeable with character values (ie `aX` is very different from `"aX"`).

So when putting together a formula from string values, I suggest you use the `reformualte()` function. It takes a vector of names for the right-hand side and an optional value for the left hand side. So you would create the same formula with

```
reformulate("ernie", "bert")
# bert ~ ernie
```

And you can use the with your lm

```
lm(reformulate(bVAR, aVAR), data = df)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm too lazy to search for a duplicate on how to construct formulas programmatically, so here is a solution:

```
varlist <- c("X", "Y")

for(i in 1:length(varlist)){
  #make these symbols:
  aVAR <- as.symbol(paste0("a", varlist[i]))
  bVAR <- as.symbol(paste0("b", varlist[i])) 

  #VAR and cVAR appear to have names identical column names in the df dataframe
  print(c(aVAR, bVAR))

  #Try the formula with the loop variable names
  #construct the call to `lm` with `bquote` and `eval` the expression
  print((broom::glance(eval(bquote(lm(.(aVAR) ~ .(bVAR), data = df)))))$r.squared)
}
```

Comment: I prefer `print((broom::glance(lm(reformulate(bVAR, aVAR), data = df)))$r.squared)` myself to avoid `eval()`

Comment: @MrFlick I see no reason to avoid `eval`. My solution using `eval` is superior to all other solutions I have tried. E.g., it prints a nice formula in `summary` output, in contrast to your suggestion.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess my bigger concern was more readability (which is subjective). But obviously both work.