# Prediction in R - GLMM

Tags: r, prediction, glm, lme4

When we use a traditional logistic regression and make a prediction in R, for example:

```
library(dplyr)
n = 300
xx<-c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5")
xxx<-c("e1","e2","e3")
p=0.3
df1 <- data_frame(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
 School = factor(sample(xxx, n,re=TRUE)),
 Rank = factor(sample(xx, n,re=TRUE)),
 yx = as.factor(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = p))
)
df1
mm<-glm(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + School + Rank,binomial,df1)
n11 = data.frame(School="e3",Rank="r2",xx1=8.58,xx2=8.75,xx3=7.92)
```

We use:

```
predict(mm, n11, type="response") #No meu caso especifico
```

ou predict(mm, n11)

depending on what interests us, no Problem.

But when we work with GLMM

```
library(lme4)
mm2 <- glmer(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + Rank +  (Rank | School), data = df1, 
family = "binomial",control = glmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE))
predict(mm2, n11, type="response") #No meu caso especifico
```

Displays the error

```
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I tried to do so

```
 predict(m2,n11, re.form=(~Rank|School))
```

This displays the error

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "glmmadmb"
```

What would be the correct form of the prediction in R - GLMM?

Comment: `n11 = data.frame(School=factor("e3", levels = levels(df1$School)),
                 Rank=factor("r2", levels = levels(df1$Rank)),xx1=8.58,xx2=8.75,xx3=7.92)`

Comment: @Roland, please post as answer? I've started an issue [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/452) (We try to cover these cases, but I clearly haven't got all edge [?] cases covered ...)

Comment: BTW in the second example you're clearly trying to predict with a `glmmadmb` object rather than a `merMod` (lme4) object ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your model specification doesn't match the structure of the new data you provide. More specifically, the levels of the (automatically converted to factor) variables School and Rank only have a single level, whereas the model expects three levels.  It has parameters for three levels, so if those three levels can't be found, you can't use the proper design matrix to calculate the new predictions.

That's the underlying reason as to why @Roland is right in the comments and that you have to specifically create a variable with the same levels as used in the data that trained the model.

```
n11 <- data.frame(School=factor("e3", levels = levels(df1$School)), 
                  Rank=factor("r2", levels =levels(df1$Rank)),
                  xx1=8.58,xx2=8.75,xx3=7.92)
```

Comment: FWIW this problem is now fixed in the development version of lme4 (1.1-16, on github)