# Error in RServe with Tableau For Logistic regression

Tags: r, tableau-api

Referring to the this link [Prediction In Tableau](https://www.interworks.com/blog/jbajon/2016/01/07/predicting-flu-tableau-and-r) I am making a logistic regression model in Tableau using R script.
Every time i get the error

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Need to build a nested calculation in tableau but not sure what is the hierarchy tableau follow. Need to give users a filter which they can select and see the probability of purchase.
Attached is the sample workbook as well.

Comment: Reports of errors need data (your data or data that allows us to reproduce the error) and code to support them. Just posting an error message is almost never enough.

Comment: Please find the link for the twbx file https://drive.google.com/open?id=14HS7zqz1gPRHyJmeMKci3iCFio5SQT1n

Comment: Those of us R users have no way to determine what sort of code you are throwing at the R engine. I can open that file and use my text editor to view the workbook code because it is an xml file inside. But it's big and I have no idea where to look in it if it indeed contains the r code.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the questions above, as there is no factor in my data which has a single category. the code used is  `dat <- na.omit(aa)`. Here aa is the CSV i had read. ## extract factor columns and drop redundant levels
 `fctr <- lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)], droplevels)`
 ## count levels
 `sapply(fctr, nlevels)`. The result of sapply is TV_NTV_CATEGORY   NEW_CAR_MODEL     DEALER_ZONE    SERVICE_TYPE          GENDER      OCCUPATION 
              2              14               5              17               2              29

Comment: Sometimes there are procedures that do subsetting of data before passing to glm(...) which is the underlying logistic regression function. The subsetting may create a data-object that  has only one level of a factor.

Comment: If you want better R help you may need to produce a copy of the data in a form that non-license holders of Tableau can work on. Your question is a) not-reproducible and b) based on a commercial software product that is no available to most of us R-users.