# R regression analysis: analyzing data for a certain ethnicity

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a data set that investigate depression among individuals with different ethnicities (Black, White, and Latina).

I want to know how depression at baseline relates to depression at post with all ethnic groups, I did

```
lm(depression_base ~ depression_post, data=Data
```

Now, I want to look at the relationship by ethnicity. Ethnicity in my dataset is coded as `0 = White`, `1 = Black`, and `2 = Latina`. I am thinking that I need to use the `ifelse` function, but I cannot seem to get it to work. Here is what I tried for `White`:

```
lm(depression_base[ifelse, ethnicity == 0],
   depression_post[ifelse, ethnicity == 0])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code your `ethnicity` as factors with correct levels, then do a single regression:

```
## recode your 0, 1, 2 from numeric to factor
Data$ethnicity <- factor(Data$ethnicity)
fit <- lm(depression_base ~ depression_post * ethnicity, data = Data)
```

A single model allows you decent test for variability between groups.

You might be confused about the meaning of the coefficients. If so, have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222013/how-to-interpret-dummy-and-ratio-variable-interactions-in-r/222014#222014) or other posts on CrossValidated.