# Recursive Feature Elimination - Linear Model - R

Tags: r, linear-regression, rfe

I am trying to solve the [Ames Housing Data Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data), and have removed columns that contain NA values greater than 5%, and further eliminated additional rows with NA values.

I am trying to eliminate features for a linear model using caret. I have setup the following code,

```
control <- rfeControl(functions=lmFuncs, method="cv", number=5)    
results <- rfe(x[, 1:ncol(x)-1], x[, "SalePrice"], sizes=c(1:ncol(x)-1), rfeControl=control)
```

To which the following error results,

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "contrasts can be applied only to factors
>   with 2 or more levels"

The things is, all factors of x have levels greater than 2!

Here is a str output of the data,

```
'data.frame':   1460 obs. of  75 variables:
 $ MSSubClass   : int  60 20 60 70 60 50 20 60 50 190 ...
 $ MSZoning     : Factor w/ 5 levels "C (all)","FV",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 4 ...
 $ LotFrontage  : int  65 80 68 60 84 85 75 NA 51 50 ...
 $ LotArea      : int  8450 9600 11250 9550 14260 14115 10084 10382 6120 7420 ...
 $ Street       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Grvl","Pave": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ LotShape     : Factor w/ 4 levels "IR1","IR2","IR3",..: 4 4 1 1 1 1 4 1 4 4 ...
 $ LandContour  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Bnk","HLS","Low",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Utilities    : Factor w/ 2 levels "AllPub","NoSeWa": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LotConfig    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Corner","CulDSac",..: 5 3 5 1 3 5 5 1 5 1 ...
 $ LandSlope    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Gtl","Mod","Sev": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Neighborhood : Factor w/ 25 levels "Blmngtn","Blueste",..: 6 25 6 7 14 12 21 17 18 4 ...
 $ Condition1   : Factor w/ 9 levels "Artery","Feedr",..: 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 5 1 1 ...
 $ Condition2   : Factor w/ 8 levels "Artery","Feedr",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ BldgType     : Factor w/ 5 levels "1Fam","2fmCon",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ HouseStyle   : Factor w/ 8 levels "1.5Fin","1.5Unf",..: 6 3 6 6 6 1 3 6 1 2 ...
 $ OverallQual  : int  7 6 7 7 8 5 8 7 7 5 ...
 $ OverallCond  : int  5 8 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 6 ...
 $ YearBuilt    : int  2003 1976 2001 1915 2000 1993 2004 1973 1931 1939 ...
 $ YearRemodAdd : int  2003 1976 2002 1970 2000 1995 2005 1973 1950 1950 ...
 $ RoofStyle    : Factor w/ 6 levels "Flat","Gable",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ RoofMatl     : Factor w/ 8 levels "ClyTile","CompShg",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Exterior1st  : Factor w/ 15 levels "AsbShng","AsphShn",..: 13 9 13 14 13 13 13 7 4 9 ...
 $ Exterior2nd  : Factor w/ 16 levels "AsbShng","AsphShn",..: 14 9 14 16 14 14 14 7 16 9 ...
 $ MasVnrType   : Factor w/ 4 levels "BrkCmn","BrkFace",..: 2 3 2 3 2 3 4 4 3 3 ...
 $ MasVnrArea   : int  196 0 162 0 350 0 186 240 0 0 ...
 $ ExterQual    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ ExterCond    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Foundation   : Factor w/ 6 levels "BrkTil","CBlock",..: 3 2 3 1 3 6 3 2 1 1 ...
 $ BsmtQual     : Factor w/ 4 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 3 3 3 4 3 3 1 3 4 4 ...
 $ BsmtCond     : Factor w/ 4 levels "Fa","Gd","Po",..: 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ BsmtExposure : Factor w/ 4 levels "Av","Gd","Mn",..: 4 2 3 4 1 4 1 3 4 4 ...
 $ BsmtFinType1 : Factor w/ 6 levels "ALQ","BLQ","GLQ",..: 3 1 3 1 3 3 3 1 6 3 ...
 $ BsmtFinSF1   : int  706 978 486 216 655 732 1369 859 0 851 ...
 $ BsmtFinType2 : Factor w/ 6 levels "ALQ","BLQ","GLQ",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 2 6 6 ...
 $ BsmtFinSF2   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 0 0 ...
 $ BsmtUnfSF    : int  150 284 434 540 490 64 317 216 952 140 ...
 $ TotalBsmtSF  : int  856 1262 920 756 1145 796 1686 1107 952 991 ...
 $ Heating      : Factor w/ 6 levels "Floor","GasA",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ HeatingQC    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ CentralAir   : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Electrical   : Factor w/ 5 levels "FuseA","FuseF",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 5 ...
 $ X1stFlrSF    : int  856 1262 920 961 1145 796 1694 1107 1022 1077 ...
 $ X2ndFlrSF    : int  854 0 866 756 1053 566 0 983 752 0 ...
 $ LowQualFinSF : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ GrLivArea    : int  1710 1262 1786 1717 2198 1362 1694 2090 1774 1077 ...
 $ BsmtFullBath : int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ BsmtHalfBath : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FullBath     : int  2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ HalfBath     : int  1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ BedroomAbvGr : int  3 3 3 3 4 1 3 3 2 2 ...
 $ KitchenAbvGr : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ KitchenQual  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ TotRmsAbvGrd : int  8 6 6 7 9 5 7 7 8 5 ...
 $ Functional   : Factor w/ 7 levels "Maj1","Maj2",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 3 7 ...
 $ Fireplaces   : int  0 1 1 1 1 0 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ GarageType   : Factor w/ 6 levels "2Types","Attchd",..: 2 2 2 6 2 2 2 2 6 2 ...
 $ GarageYrBlt  : int  2003 1976 2001 1998 2000 1993 2004 1973 1931 1939 ...
 $ GarageFinish : Factor w/ 3 levels "Fin","RFn","Unf": 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ GarageCars   : int  2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ GarageArea   : int  548 460 608 642 836 480 636 484 468 205 ...
 $ GarageQual   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2 3 ...
 $ GarageCond   : Factor w/ 5 levels "Ex","Fa","Gd",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ PavedDrive   : Factor w/ 3 levels "N","P","Y": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ WoodDeckSF   : int  0 298 0 0 192 40 255 235 90 0 ...
 $ OpenPorchSF  : int  61 0 42 35 84 30 57 204 0 4 ...
 $ EnclosedPorch: int  0 0 0 272 0 0 0 228 205 0 ...
 $ X3SsnPorch   : int  0 0 0 0 0 320 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ScreenPorch  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PoolArea     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ MiscVal      : int  0 0 0 0 0 700 0 350 0 0 ...
 $ MoSold       : int  2 5 9 2 12 10 8 11 4 1 ...
 $ YrSold       : int  2008 2007 2008 2006 2008 2009 2007 2009 2008 2008 ...
 $ SaleType     : Factor w/ 9 levels "COD","Con","ConLD",..: 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ SaleCondition: Factor w/ 6 levels "Abnorml","AdjLand",..: 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 1 5 ...
 $ SalePrice    : int  208500 181500 223500 140000 250000 143000 307000 200000 129900 118000 ...
```

Please help!

Comment: Hi, please consider how to make a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and see how you can change your question accordingly.
From what you posted, we can not help you, as we don't know which packages and data you are using.

Comment: Hi @heck1, i have revised the question. Would appreciate if you could advise further.

Comment: Thats a good start. It would be great if we could see the data you are using. There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient.

Comment: It may be that after cleaning your data, some column may have only 1 unique value. Try : `lapply(x,function(y){  if(is.character(y) | is.factor(y))  unique(y)  else range(y)}) `    . Check the output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er)

Comment: @heck1, I've included a summary of the data.

Comment: @Rohit, lapply defaults to column operations?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed the issue.

1. Yes, this question is [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er).

Something to keep in mind about contrasts,

1. Your summary might indicate that all factors have levels greater than 2. This was the most mystifying issue I had with this problem. You must consider that they actually have less than 2 levels, for some reason you don't understand.
2. I ended up using the function, [debug_contr_error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er) to figure out columns that had less than 2 factor levels.
3. I then excluded the column from the lm regression.

Hope this helps you!