# Writing a function that converts variable modes and classes

Tags: r, function, class, data-cleaning

I use the following code ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er/44201384#44201384)) to clean potentially troublesome aspects of the data for a hypothetical df called `dataframe`:

```
dataframe <- fread(
    "A   B  B.x  C  D   E   iso   year   
     0   3   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     1   4   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     0   5   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     1   5   NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     1   1   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     0   1   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
     0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
     1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
     0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
     1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)

dataframe <- as.data.frame(dataframe)
## get mode of all vars
var_mode <- sapply(dataframe, mode)
## produce error if complex or raw is found
if (any(var_mode %in% c("complex", "raw"))) stop("complex or raw not allowed!")
## get class of all vars
var_class <- sapply(dataframe, class)
## produce error if an "AsIs" object has "logical" or "character" mode
if (any(var_mode[var_class == "AsIs"] %in% c("logical", "character"))) {
  stop("matrix variables with 'AsIs' class must be 'numeric'")
  }
## identify columns that needs be coerced to factors
ind1 <- which(var_mode %in% c("logical", "character"))
## coerce logical / character to factor with `as.factor`
dataframe[ind1] <- lapply(dataframe[ind1], as.factor)
```

As I use it a lot I would however prefer to put it in a function and tried the following:

```
cleanfunction <- function(dataframe) {
dataframe <- as.data.frame(dataframe)
## get mode of all vars
var_mode <- sapply(dataframe, mode)
## produce error if complex or raw is found
if (any(var_mode %in% c("complex", "raw"))) stop("complex or raw not allowed!")
## get class of all vars
var_class <- sapply(dataframe, class)
## produce error if an "AsIs" object has "logical" or "character" mode
if (any(var_mode[var_class == "AsIs"] %in% c("logical", "character"))) {
  stop("matrix variables with 'AsIs' class must be 'numeric'")
  }
## identify columns that needs be coerced to factors
ind1 <- which(var_mode %in% c("logical", "character"))
## coerce logical / character to factor with `as.factor`
dataframe[ind1] <- lapply(dataframe[ind1], as.factor)
}

dfclean <- cleanfunction(dataframe)
```

This however created a list of variables converted to factors instead of a dataframe which has these variables converted to factors.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions return the value from the last expression evaluated. In this case the last expression evauluated is

```
dataframe[ind1] <- lapply(dataframe[ind1], as.factor)
```

and the `<-` operation always just returns the right hand side value. So you are just returning the results from the `lapply`, not the updated `dataframe`.

You just need to add another line that says

```
return(dataframe)
```

or just

```
dataframe
```

to the end of your function.