# error while running debugging while using GLM model

Tags: r, debugging, package

I am trying to run a glm regression analysis. I am getting an error

```
# Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Now I have read many threads where this problem has been discussed by using `debug_contr_error(data)` but I am getting another error that

```
# Error in debug_contr_error(data) : 
  could not find function "debug_contr_error"
```

I think I am missing some package installation here. Can anyone please help. The code that I am using for glm regression (my data frame is 'data' and placed is one of the column names)

```
model <- glm(placed ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=data)
```

Comment: That function is defined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44201384/2372064. It is not something that's built into R  itself or a package.

Comment: You are probably using a categorical predictor with just one level. As such it cannot contribute to the model.