# Is there a way to ignore one-level factors during a mapped regression (for some subsets)?

Tags: r, regression, purrr, lm

I want to run a series of linear regressions on subsets of a dataframe (subset by about 100 occupations). One of the explanatory variables is a factor. For some subsets (ie occupations), this factor only has one level, but it is very important that I include where I can. When I split the data and map the regression, I get an error about contrasts. I know why this is happening, but **is there a way to attempt to use explantory categorical variables in a formula but drop them if they are only one level?**

I've seen the [post about debugging this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er/44201384), but that does not account for the mapping component that I'm attempting.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create reprex data 
# Here, there are only male plumbers, which will cause a problem later
df <- tibble(wage = rnorm(10, 100, 15),
             occupation = c(rep("Plumber", 5),
                            rep("Electrician", 5)),
             hours = rnorm(10, 40, 5),
             sex = c(rep("Male", 5),
                     rep("Male", 2), 
                     rep("Female", 3)))

glimpse(df)
#> Observations: 10
#> Variables: 4
#> $ wage       <dbl> 107.69546, 117.79401, 102.75925, 108.66250, 100.716...
#> $ occupation <chr> "Plumber", "Plumber", "Plumber", "Plumber", "Plumbe...
#> $ hours      <dbl> 51.73202, 37.13047, 38.20627, 41.00303, 39.14806, 3...
#> $ sex        <chr> "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Ma...


# Split the df by occupation and run a regression to explain wages
df %>% 
  split(.$occupation) %>% 
  map(~lm(wage ~ hours + sex,
          data = .))
#> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I know why the contrasts error is occuring (becuase there are only males in the plumbers split), but is there a way to wrap 'sex' in something so that it's used if it can be, and dropped if it cannot? Or is there some syntex other than `split` & `map` that I can use to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

```
by(df[-2],df[2],function(x){
  y<-x[sapply(x,function(i)length(unique(i)))>1]
  lm(wage~.,y)
})

occupation: Electrician

Call:
lm(formula = wage ~ ., data = y)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        hours      sexMale  
   101.5222      -0.2763       9.0678  

---------------------------------------------------------------- 
occupation: Plumber

Call:
lm(formula = wage ~ ., data = y)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        hours  
   128.9323      -0.7343
```

Answer (score 0):

Onyambu's answer is correct. If you want to use purrr you can use `map_if` to test for the number of unique factors and then apply different models with the .else argument. Just make sure you have a relatively recent (2019) version of purrr.

```
df %>% 
    split(.$occupation) %>%
    map_if(function (x) length(unique(x$sex)) > 1, ~lm(wage ~ hours + sex, data = .), 
           .else = ~lm(wage ~ hours, data = .))
```