# `ggeffect` or `Effect`cannot estimate marginal effects in model after checking factor levels and missing data

Tags: r, r-haven, marginal-effects

Using data imported with `haven` from a dataset that includes labels, I cannot get marginal effects using `ggeffect()` from the package `ggeffects` or `Effect()` from the package `effects`

When using these functions an error gets prompted, although having checked the number of levels and missing cases in the predictors of a model. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er) explains how to debug these last cases, avoiding empty factor levels or missing cases which will impede getting the marginal effects.

Although, in the absence of these problems I still get the error message from `ggeffect()`: `Can't compute marginal effects, 'effects::Effect()' returned an error.`; or in `effects::Effect()`: `Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]])` because some predictor object was not found.

What else can I check in my data to get the marginal effects computed?

Comment: If you would like to preserve value Android variable labels, you could try to import the data with `sjlabelled::read_spss()`. Does this help?

Comment: Great! Yes, it helps.  Nonetheless, OP assumes having read the data with `haven`

Comment: "The goal of haven is not to provide a labelled vector that you can use everywhere in your analysis. The goal is to provide an intermediate datastructure that you can convert into a regular R data frame." (https://haven.tidyverse.org/articles/semantics.html). `sjlabelled::read_spss()` uses haven, but coerces the data into a format (i.e. numeric, factor, ...) that is "readable" by other packages w/o losing the value and variable labels. Same can be used to set/get labels, see http://strengejacke.github.io/sjlabelled for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reason that will impede computing marginal effects with `effects::Effect()` (or with `ggpredict::ggeffect()` which uses this same function) is the existence of labelled variables in the data, i.e., those columns of class `haven_labelled`. This class of variables is common when importing datasets in foreign formats (e.g., SPSS, Stata, SAS) with the `haven` library.

In the following example it's clear when does the problem arises:

```
# Load libraries
library(ggeffects)
library(haven)

# Fit model with no labelled variables
ex1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl,
               data = mtcars)
ggeffect(ex1, term = c("cyl"))
#> 
#> # Predicted values of mpg
#> # x = cyl
#> 
#> x | Predicted |   SE |         95% CI
#> -------------------------------------
#> 4 |     26.38 | 0.90 | [24.53, 28.23]
#> 6 |     20.63 | 0.57 | [19.47, 21.79]
#> 8 |     14.88 | 0.81 | [13.22, 16.54]

# Label one value of variable cyl
mtcars$cyl2 <- labelled(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("6" = 6))

# Fit model with the value-labelled variable cyl2
ex2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl2,
               data = mtcars)
ggeffect(ex2, term = c("cyl2"))
#> Can't compute marginal effects, 'effects::Effect()' returned an error.
#> 
#> Reason: non-conformable arguments
#> You may try 'ggpredict()' or 'ggemmeans()'.
#> NULL
effects::Effect(ex2, "cyl2")
#> Error in eval(parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)[[1L]]): object 'cyl2' not found
```

To check if there are columns of type `haven_labelled` in your data you can use `str(data)` and change those who hold this class to a relevant one. One way to check the class of your For example, you can check the classes of the columns with this code:

```
library(haven)
mtcars$cyl2 <- labelled(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("6" = 6))
str(mtcars)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  12 variables:
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
#>  $ cyl2: 'haven_labelled' num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num 6
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "6"
```

Comment: I upvoted all your answers as a way to support, welcome to SO :-)